# Error on sending mail programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, console, smtp

I am trying to send an e-mail from a simple console application using my company's mail server:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("myemail@mycompany.com", "myemail@mycompany.com", "test", "testbody");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.mycompany.com", 465);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@mycompany.com", "myPassword");
client.EnableSsl = true;            
client.Send(mm);
Console.WriteLine("email sent");
Console.ReadKey();
```

I am getting the following error: "Failure sending mail.", innerException is "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."

I have tried connecting to the mail server on that specific port via telnet, which was working fine. My login credentials were also tested on the webmail client and I was authenticated correctly. I have checked my firewall settings, and let Visual Studio through the firewall.

Any ideas what could cause the problem?

Regards,
Adam

Comment: Can it be some problem With the SSL? When you checked the server on port 465, you probably couln't test the Connection With SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ssl to false and setting the port number to 25.
Also double check wether the smtp server is open, because then you won't need the login authentication parameters.

Comment: Thank you, this one worked, but I would like to send in a more secure manner.

Comment: check this example out, have not tested it, but looks promising.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, check this out, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13236/Sending-complex-emails-in-NET-1-1